# From old to new layout in Google books

Tags: google-books

Sometimes on books.google.com the layout of the page is the old one (see figure below please). Is there a way to switch to the new one?

**Old**
[image]

**New**
[image]

---

EDIT: the option suggested in the reply is not present. you can check [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=xvwgEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA56&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false).

[image]

Comment: Hi. Have you tried access "Google Books" as an app and make your search from there?

Comment: Hello @Tedinoz I'm using my laptop to do research because it's more confortable.

Comment: Laptop/desktop makes no difference.  If you’re running  Chrome, then you can access the Google Books App but clicking the Waffle/AppLauncher and then selecting Books.

Comment: @Tedinoz I searched Google Books but without any good result. See here please: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/google%20books?hl=en-GB&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher

Comment: [Google Books](https://books.google.com/)

Comment: @Tedinoz thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the old and new Google Books have a settings icon ([image: Settings]).

- When you are in the new Books, there is an option to "Go back to classic Google Books."
- When you are in the Old Books, there is an options to "Try the new Google Books"

[image: Settings]

---

Comment: Hello @Tedinoz, se the edit please.

Comment: Two things: 1)Your url = `https://books.google.it/...`. My url = `https://www.google.com.au/books/...` The book id "xvwgEAAAQBAJ" is identical. 2) Page 56 is not available as preview in my url.